# Riemann integral of $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{m=1}^n \tan^{-1}$$1\over(1+m+m^2)$

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

For any real number $x$, $\tan^{-1}(x)$ denote unique real number $\theta$ in (-$\pi\over2$, $\pi\over2$) such that $\tan\theta=x$. Then evaluate

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $\sum_{m=1}^n \tan^{-1}$$1\over(1+m+m^2)$

My approach: I separated the above to $\tan^{-1}(m+1)-\tan^{-1}(m)$

But I could not proceed further. I sense that it needs to be converted into a Riemann integral, however I am not being able to do that.

Comment: Your approach was definitely correct. Write out the first 4 or so terms and you will very quickly see that you have a self-cancelling sum (telescoping sum). 

Try that and see where it leads.

Comment: Then, is the answer (pi/4)

Comment: See [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).